# Dynamic templates and routing in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am developing a meteor.js application. I have two main templates/pages, home.html and groups.html. I render these templates according to the selection of main menu. In home template, I just show basic informations about the website. But in groups template, I have side menu which has timeline, chat, group blog options, and according to the selection of side menu, I render timeline or chat or groupblog templates inside groups template. I succeeded this with two different methods.

Can you please tell me if any of them is correct approach, and if they both are, which one is better to use?

In the first approach, is there any way to wait to render sub-template until data is ready, like waitOn property in iron-router?

First approach: I am using dynamic template, and rendering and setting data contex of sub-templates by using Session variable.

```
layout.html
 <template name="layout">
  <div>
    {{> header}}
    <div id="main" class="container">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
 </div>
</template>


groups.html
<template name="groups">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
           {{> dynamictemplate}}
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</template>

dynamictemplate.html
 <template name="dynamictemplate">
   {{#DynamicTemplate template=getTemplate data=getData}}
    Default content when there is no template.
   {{/DynamicTemplate}}
</template>

dynamictemplate.js
Template.dynamictemplate.helpers({
getData: function () {
    var tempname="timeline";
    if(Session.get("menuitemselected")!=null){
        tempname =Session.get("menuitemselected");
    }
    if(tempname=="timeline"){
        return {test:123};
    }else if(tempname=="calendar"){
        return {groupId:this._id};
    }
   },
   getTemplate: function () {
    var tempname="timeline";
    if(Session.get("menuitemselected")!=null){
        tempname =Session.get("menuitemselected");

    }
    return tempname;
  }
 });
```

Second approach, I am defining new routes for all sub-templates in routes, and I am using yield with region property in home template.(I do not know if i am supposed to use yield in any place other than layout.html)

```
layout.html
<template name="layout">
 <div>
{{> header}}
<div id="main" class="container">
    {{> yield}}
</div>
</div>
</template>

groups.html
<template name="groups">
<div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        {{> sidemenu}}
     </div>
     <div id="main" class="col-md-9">
        {{> yield region="detailrender"}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>

 router.js
.....
this.route('groupdetail', {
    path: '/groupsmain/:_id',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'timeline': {to: 'detailrender'}
    },
    data: function() { return Groups.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
  this.route('groupdetailcalendar', {
    path: '/groupsmain/:_id/calendar',
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    template: 'groupdetail',
    yieldTemplates: {
        'calendar': {to: 'detailrender'}
    },
    data: function() { return Groups.findOne(this.params._id);
    .....
   });
```

Comment: I liked your second option because the clean separation of templates. But I have seen samples of the first approach as well.